# Restygwt: malformed URI sequence

Tags: java, encode, resty-gwt

I've REST-based service on resygwt with API like this:

```
@Path("/search")
@GET
List<User> search(@QueryParam("login") String loginMask) throws RemoteException;
```

And I receive "**malformed URI sequence**" for this request:

```
http://devsys23:8080/rest/search?login=%25spa%20ce%25
```

This is rather strange, since in JavaDoc mentioned, that such requests should be supported by default:

> - Binds the value(s) of a HTTP query parameter to a resource method parameter,
> - resource class field, or resource class bean property.
> - Values are URL decoded unless this is disabled using the {@link Encoded}
> - annotation. A default value can be specified using the {@link DefaultValue}
> - annotation.

I've try to edit tomcat connector in server.xml with useBodyEncodingForURI and URIEncoding="UTF-8". Also org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter was included and forceEncoding set, but it still doesn't work =(

What should I do to specify that login param should be decoded?
Thank you for your advice if any.

Comment: Is your problem realy related to RestyGWT ?  From what I understand the problem is more a tomcat problem for decoding query param values. Do you want resty not to encode query param or do you want your backend to decode them ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decode the value, you can create a `ContainerResponseFilter`, register it in your `ResourceConfig` and do something like

```
String loginValue= queryParams.get("login");
loginValue= URLDecoder.decode(loginValue, "UTF-8");
```

Maybe RestyGWT is encoding all the params by default.

Need to ask on the restyGWT google discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restygwt